How to disable Recapcha in a hostinger hosted wesbite
I have a php website hosted on hostinger, everything was ok. But suddenly the users to verify that they are not a robot before entering. I did not add that or enable that myself. You can see the picture below. It appears everytime someone tries to access my wesbite.
This is very annoying, I want to disable that. I looked for a solution and I could not find a guide for that.
Can you please help? I don't want recaptcha in the website


Did you contact the hosting company's support line about this? Did you check the settings in your hosting account's control panel? We're here to answer programming questions, but from what you've said this doesn't seem to be anything to do with your code.

check the hosted domain if there is any setting to enable recaptcha. Hosting sites like cloudflare has an option to verify humans to prevent ddos attacks.

Check your hosting provider for any settings to enable reCAPTCHA. Hosting sites like Cloudflare has an option to verify humans to prevent DDOS attacks.

The above is for Cloudflare. Similarly check with your provider for any related settings. The issue is not with your code.
